# fputcsv - Function gives Error.

Tags: php, fputcsv

I'm trying to export my data into a csv file and let the user to download it. I'm using fputcsv() function, but in the file, the data are written in a single cell instead of adjacent cells. I don't know what is the problem. Please help me. here is my code

```
session_start();
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=report_'.time().'.csv;');
$data = $_SESSION['data'];
$file = fopen('php://output','w');
foreach($data as $i=>$value)
{
    fputcsv($file, $value,";");
}
fclose($file);
```

and this is how the file looks like..

[image: and this is how the file looks like..]

Comment: Try this fputcsv($fp, array_values($list), ';', ' ');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like

```
 $data = array (
    'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
    '123,456,789',
    '"aaa","bbb"');
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w+'); 
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');  
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="data.csv"'); 
foreach($data as $line){
    $val = explode(",",$line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
```

or try may be according your data

```
foreach($data as $i=>$value)
{
    fputcsv($file, $value);
}
```

Comment: change according to your data

Comment: thank you so much, it works. can you explain what is wrong in my code if you have some time?

Comment: i think delimiter(;) you are using is wrong for more http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php please accept every answer if you find correct with that

Answer (score 1):

Use `,` instead of `;` for `delimiter`

Replace `fputcsv($file, $value,";");` with `fputcsv($file, $value, ",");` and try

Example:

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename=report_'.time().'.csv;');
$data = array(array('one' => 1, 'two' => 2));
$file = fopen('php://output','w');
foreach($data as $i => $value)
{
    //fputcsv($file, $value, ";");
    fputcsv($file, $value, ",");
}
fclose($file);
```